# Golang Twitter API - update_profile_banner Image COMPRESSION_ERROR

Tags: api, http, go, twitter

I am trying to update banner image using [account/update_profile_banner.json](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/manage-account-settings/api-reference/post-account-update_profile_banner) in Twitter API.
In the query parameter, it is said that the image can be sent in 2 format types. as base64 or raw data.

When I encode my image with base64, I think its size exceeds the maximum http length. Sending as binary seems more illogical as it would be longer than base64.

```golang
Post "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/update_profile_banner.json?banner=%2F9j%2F2wCEAA...": http2: server sent GOAWAY and closed the connection; LastStreamID=7, ErrCode=COMPRESSION_ERROR, debug=""
```

The library I use is [dghubble/go-twitter](https://github.com/dghubble/go-twitter), but I had to create a [fork](https://github.com/sercanarga/go-twitter-added-profile-banner/blob/master/twitter/accounts.go) since there is no method to update the profile banner. I added the following function and struct to the accounts.go file.

```golang
type AccountUpdateProfileBannerPhotoParams struct {
    Banner string `url:"banner,omitempty"`
    Width   int    `url:"width,omitempty"`
    Height  int    `url:"height,omitempty"`
    OffsetX int    `url:"offset_left,omitempty"`
    OffsetY int    `url:"offset_top,omitempty"`
}

func (s *AccountService) UpdateProfileBannerPhoto(params *AccountUpdateProfileBannerPhotoParams) (*User, *http.Response, error) {
    user := new(User)
    apiError := new(APIError)
    resp, err := s.sling.New().Post("update_profile_banner.json").QueryStruct(params).Receive(user, apiError)
    return user, resp, relevantError(err, *apiError)
}
```

The `UpdateProfileBannerPhoto()` function returns the above error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the problem. Carelessness!

I learned that Twitter used the [media/upload](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/media/upload-media/api-reference/post-media-upload) method and then updated the `media_id` value by sending it to the [account/update_profile_banner](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/media/upload-media/api-reference/post-media-upload) method by following the network traffic.

But it is not needed. I updated the `QueryStruct` in the `UpdateProfileBannerPhoto` function with `BodyForm` and the problem was solved...

Fixed:

```golang
func (s *AccountService) UpdateProfileBannerPhoto(params *AccountUpdateProfileBannerPhotoParams) (*User, *http.Response, error) {
    user := new(User)
    apiError := new(APIError)
    resp, err := s.sling.New().Post("update_profile_banner.json").BodyForm(params).Receive(user, apiError)
    return user, resp, relevantError(err, *apiError)
}
```